# Java: Find string in array list

Tags: java, arrays, string

My arraylist consists of an array with a list of strings, each string inside is separated by commas, i want to split one of the strings into substrings divided by the commas, i know how to do it to arrays by using the split method, but im having trouble finding something similar to array lists, heres the code:

```
String[] widgets2 = 
        {

            "1,John,Smith,John1989@gmail.com,20,88,79,59",
            "2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,91,72,85",
            "3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,85,84,87",
            "4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,91,98,82",
            "5,Adan,Ramirez,networkturtle66@gmail.com,100,100,100"

        };

         ArrayList<String> jim = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(widgets2));

System.out.println(jim.split(0));
```

Comment: Java 7: loops, loops and more loops (well, just one explicit loop: pretend it is C).

Comment: `jim.get(index).split()` probably? How did you do it in arrays?

Comment: Please change your profile picture.

Comment: `jim.get(0).split(",")` may be?

Comment: jim.get(0).split(",") produces: [Ljava.lang.String;@19e0bfd

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, seriously? Is it because you can't resist looking at it? If you find it offensive submit a flag and let the powers that be settle it. Seems like similar to what you'd see at any public beach.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils FYI its not a Public beach/Facebook/Twitter profile its a Pro coding website, are we promoting nudity here? What will happen if someone will put Naked image? Then again you will say "All Porn site contain this if you have a problem flag it" ?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, firstly this isn't a "Pro" coding site - read about it. Secondly, that's not nudity by many people's standards hence the beach comment. If someone posts a nude pic then it's a different scenario. You're proposing a slippery-slope argument. I appreciate you trying to guess how I would react to certain things, but you're wrong. Porn is more generally, and logically, offensive no need to oppress one's expression. Again, flag it if you have a problem with it; that's how this kinda thing works.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and **enthusiast** programmers."

Comment: the image im using is not nudity, it's a character screenshot from the PC game: dead or alive 5: LR, she's wearing a cute bikini-but not naked

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to what you do with the `arrays`. Just that the implementation is different. To get the values just loop through them:

```
List<String> jim = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(widgets2));
for(String currentString : jim){//ArrayList looping
 String[] separatedStrings = currentString.split(",");
    for(String separatedString : separatedStrings){//Now its array looping
       //Do something now whatever you like to
    }
}
```

If you want to have the index and decide which value to get, use normal `for` loop using index and use `jim.get(index)` and use `split()`.

Having said that, what stops you from looping through the List ? It's the common usage of array list - to loop through it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String jim_string = jim.toString().replace("[", "");
    jim_string.replace("]", "");
    String splitted[] = jim_string.split(",");
    System.out.println(splitted[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

put the below code lines into your code, it'll give your desire output.

```
int indx=0; //use the index you want to get & split
String tmp = jim.get(indx); // get the string from the ArrayList
if(tmp!=null && !tmp.equals("")){ // null check
for (String retval: tmp.split(";")){ // split & print
     System.out.println(retval);
  }
}
```